# AWS AppSync - How to query data by date range(Today to 30 days before)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

This is how my schema.graphql looks like.

```
type Post 
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: owner }
    ]
  ) {
  id: ID!
  author: User! @connection(name: "UserPosts")
  content: AWSJSON!
  createdAt: AWSDateTime
  updatedAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

Which generated GraphQL query showing below

```
export const listPosts = `query listPosts(
  $filter: ModelPostFilterInput
  $limit: Int
  $nextToken: String
) {
  listPosts(filter: $filter, limit: $limit, nextToken: $nextToken) {
    items {
      id
      author {
        id
        uuid
      }
      content
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
`;
```

I'm calling `listPosts` to query list of Posts but not sure how to implement date range into below query that I'm using to get data.

`await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listPosts, {limit: 10, nextToken: nextToken}))`

Is it possible to add two strings `start: TODAY` and `end: 30 DAYS BEFORE TODAY` to the query above and get it returns 30 latest posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the new @key directive: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#key

Answer (score 3):

I did not try the new `@key` directive mentioned by Richard.
The solution I was using so far is to pass the parameter to the resolver and implement the query expression at resolver level.

For example, to query all bookings in the future (when booking start date is > today), I used

```
#set( $todayString = $util.time.nowISO8601().substring(0, 10) )
{
  "version": "2017-02-28",
  "operation": "Query",
  "query": {
    "expression": "guestId = :gId AND startDate > :startDate",
    "expressionValues": {
      ":gId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.guestId),
      ":startDate": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($todayString)
    }
  },
  "index": "guestId-startDate-index"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm new to AppSync and just starting to notice about resolver. Do you add that code via AWS console by adding function on AppSync page? How do you add resolvers?

Comment: Amplify will create resolvers for you.  You can modify them in `amplify/backend/api/<your API name>/resolver directory` and synchronise your project with AppSync by typing `amplify push`

Comment: I assum you are suing `amplify`, if you do not, you will find the resolver in the AppSync console, in the schema definition, look on the right side where all fields and operations are listed, you can click on links to see / update the resolvers.

Comment: Yes, I use `Amplify` but `amplify/backend/api/<your API name>/resolver directory` is empty. Not sure what I'm missing...